# How to set value to globle variable in Subscribe method's value in Angular Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to know how to take out values from subscribe method and set it as a global variable. So I can use it anywhere of my typescript file

```
    constructor(
        private VNFCInstanceServicesService: VNFCInstanceServicesService,
    ) {
        this.siteId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.siteId;
        this.vnfInsId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.vnfInstanceId;
        this.VNFCInstanceServicesService.filterVnfciServices(
            this.vnfInsId,
            this.siteId,
            0
        ).subscribe((data) => {
            this.source.load(data.payload.records);
        });
   }
```

I need to take this (data.payload.records) as an global variable value

Comment: You _cannot_ use an asynchronous data synchronously. Any statements that directly depend on the data from the observable _must_ be inside the subscription. In other words you need to subscribe where it's response is required. You could however look into caching mechanisms using `shareReplay` operator or `ReplaySubject` mutli-cast observable.

Answer (score 1):

I think learning how to design an observable stream that emits exactly the data you need would be most helpful to you.  In general, the code is much simpler when there are the fewest number of subscribes and local imperative "state" variables.

Instead of doing something like this:

```js
class SomeComponent {
  private siteId;
  private vnfInsId;
    
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: VNFCInstanceServicesService
  ) {
    this.siteId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.siteId;
    this.vnfInsId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.vnfInstanceId;
    this.service.filterVnfciServices(
      this.vnfInsId,
      this.siteId,
      0
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.source.load(data.payload.records);
    });
  }
}
```

You can work with observables only.  RxJS provides many operators and static functions that allow you to build up observable streams from one another.

```js
class SomeComponent {
  private siteId$   = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('siteId')));
  private vnfInsId$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('vnfInstanceId')));

  public records$  = combineLatest([this.siteId$, this.vnfInsId$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([siteId, vnfInsId]) => this.service.filterVnfciServices(vnfInsId, siteId, 0)),
    switchMap(data => this.source.load(data.payload.records))
  );

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: VNFCInstanceServicesService
  ) { 
    this.records$.subscribe(
      records => console.log('records: ', records)
    )
  }
}
```

Operators Used:

- [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) is used in the definition of `siteId$` and `vnfInsId$` to simply return the relevant key from the route's param map.
- [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) takes multiple observable sources and emits an array containing their latest values whenever either of them emit.
- [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) receives the array emitted by `combineLatest` and forms an "inner observable" from your call to `filterVnfciServices()`.  It will subscribe an emit values from this this "inner observable".
- The second `switchMap` receives the emissions from `filterVnfciServices()` and uses that to make a call to `source.load()`, then emit that result.

The neat thing about this reactive approach is that whenever any of the sources emit a new value, the observables that depend on them will automatically receive the updated value.

I will admit that the value of utilizing a fully reactive code isn't fully realized until you have a strong grasp on how these functions/operators work, but once you do... the code becomes much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

since you are in the context of a class (judging by the constructor shown), you can also add a property on that object, and then assign the value to it:

```
...
private records: any;
constructor(
  private VNFCInstanceServicesService: VNFCInstanceServicesService,
) {
    this.siteId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.siteId;
    this.vnfInsId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.vnfInstanceId;
    this.VNFCInstanceServicesService.filterVnfciServices(
    this.vnfInsId,
    this.siteId,
    0
    ).subscribe((data) => {
       this.source.load(data.payload.records);
       this.records = data.payload.records;
    });
}

private randomFn() {
  // can access your data here
  console.log(this.records);
}
```

this will make the records available in the context of the class, if you need it elsewhere, you can make it public on the class instance. Alternatively, you can also set it on the global object, that is **not encouraged** and will cause a lot of problems down the line.

Comment: I already tries this btw It won't works console says it is undefined

Comment: If `randomFn` is called after the subscribe block has run, then you should see value in `console.log`. If it's called prior to that, you'll get `undefined`.